# How to get folder path with filechooser on kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I really searched everywhere and found a couple of answers but I don't really understand it. So I appreciate if you can help me.

I have a *Filechooser* and a *Button* inside *Popup* :

```
import...

download_path = StringProperty('')
file_chooser = FileChooserListView(dirselect = True)
btn_pop_downloader = Button(
    ...
)
content_pop_download = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
content_pop_download.add_widget(file_chooser)
content_pop_download.add_widget(btn_pop_downloader)
pop_downloader = Popup(
    ...
    content = content_pop_download
)

def get_file(self):
    download_path = self.file_chooser.path

btn_pop_downloader.bind(on_release = get_file)
```

The app runs and opens the *Popup* with the *Filechooser*. But when I press the *Button* to get the path. I get the following error:

```
download_path = self.file_chooser.path
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'file_chooser'
```

I know the error is because the interpreter thinks self variable is the button. I need help to solve it and put the #$%&! folder path in the variable *download_path*

Thanks for taking the time to read.

PS: I'm pretty new. Less a month coding :)

Comment: Hey there. Please post all the relevant code. If there is a lot of code - make another small app that demonstrates your problem. Right now I have some ideas on how to help you but your code is not clear for me to be sure and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there could be error in this function:

```
def get_file(self):
    download_path = self.file_chooser.path
```

if all your code is inside some class, then get_file() should get 2 args - because when you bind function to button, then this function receive reference to this button. So first is self and second is reference to your button. So it should look like:

```
def get_file(self, button):
    download_path = self.file_chooser.path
```

But if your code is not inside any class, then it should look like:

```
def get_file(button):
    download_path = file_chooser.path
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans. Yes, the code is inside some class. A take your solutions and works well.